# How to I deploy & schedule SSIS packages with my Setup and Deployment Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, ssis

I am trying to create a setup procedure which installs my entire web application.  I am using Visual Studio's Setup and Deployment Project.  So far I've gotten it to deploy my website to the Inetpub folder, and I've also added some custom actions which allow it to run some SQL and setup my database.

The last thing I have to integrate into the setup process is my two SSIS packages.  Not only do these need to be installed, they also need to be scheduled to run nightly.

The packages are simple, and don't reference anything unusual.  They are just 2 .dtsx files.

So far, I've seen that I can use something called [dtutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966389.aspx#XSLTsection126121120120) in order to create a dtsinstall.exe file which can be run to install the SSIS packages to either the file system or the database.

First of all, is this the easiest way to do it?  And secondly, how would I go about scheduling the packages to be run nightly?

One caveat is that I need this to install silently, without prompting the user for any input.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new job in SQL Agent. In the steps panel, click New, give it a name, and for the job type, select SQL Server Integration Services Package. For the Package source, select File system, and point it to where you want the file to live.

Then you can select Schedules from the left panel, and configure how often you want it to run.

After that, you should be able to handle deployment of the SSIS package by copying the .dtsx file to the location you specified when you created the job.